# Opening Multiple ListView's from an existing ListView in Android

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-listview

**What I'm trying to do...**

All I'm trying to do is to create a large list of movies with ListView, which opens the list of songs when clicked on particular movie, and then download selected song when clicked on it.

**What I've tried...**

I've created a ListView to show all the movies, now should I create ListView Activities for the complete list (about 300)? I think that's a tough task. Can anyone suggest me a better a way. I want my list to be retrieved from mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking whether you should create a separate activity for each movie in your list, the answer is categorically: no. Your SongActivity should be able to query out the songs for any given movie (passed via the intent when you launch the activity).

In MovieActivity:

```
Intent songIntent = new Intent(this, SongActivity.class);
songIntent.putExtra("movie_id", selectedMovieId);
this.startActivity(songIntent);
```

In SongActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String movieId = getIntent().getStringExtra("movie_id");
```

Comment: so I should write a php code to retrieve an array of songs for that particualar movie name, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, query the list of songs based on the movie name (or id, as in my example above).

Comment: "selectedMovieId" is something what I get from onclicklistener, right?

Comment: Yes, it's based on the selection that the user makes in the movie ListView.